# Which data visualization library should I use

Tags: java, graph, visualization

I'm working on a web application that should visualize CDR (Call Data Record) data in some sort of multidimensional graph. We will use a java framework for the application so I'm mostly looking for a java library, but I'm also open for other suggestions if they are a better solution. The visualized data (graph) will be included in user profiles within the application. The visualization should look something like this:

[image]

*(this is just an example how the design could look, we need to think of a new design)*

I've no experience with data visualization so it would be good if the library is well documented.

Comment: Are you looking for an open-source or a proprietary solution?

Answer (score 2):

One of the new and very good frameworks out there is [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) which uses html5, css3 and svg to generate your graph. you can add user interaction very easy.

Another lib which is written in Java but a bit outdated is [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/).

Answer (score 1):

A de-facto standard in Java is [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).

But I would also suggest you to use JavaScript charting libraries like [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/). It is sometimes wise to push graph generation to the client - and the results are quite impressive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to add that the application should be compatible with all browsers, I see jqPlot hasn't been tested with IE9 and Google Chrome. What about response time, what would be faster, Java or javascript library? beacuse we have to handle a great anmount of data, so the response time is very important

Comment: If response time is your concern, moving some logic to the client might be a good idea. Also note that you will never be able to support **all** browsers. Of course generating the chart on the server side is more reliable in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking into call record visualization, you may want to peruse the awards in the [VAST 2008 Cell Phone Mini-Challenge](http://vac.nist.gov/challenge2008.html). Teams competed to create visual analytics tools to examine a set of cell phone records to try to track a group of evil-doers that switched phones to avoid detection. You may get some new visualization ideas from their results, and I'm sure some of the teams used Java libraries. You can see [all the entries here](http://vac.nist.gov/2008/cellphonechallenge.html).